# image buttons(left+right) jquery using offset().left for right click and left value in css for left click work only one time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: Example of work]

I have been practicing jQuery and I wonder if you could help me with this error.

I came across website that using arrows to move pictures and tried to learn one.

However, mine works only one click for each side. I can't make the right button shows more picture until it ends in this div. When I clicked again, it didn't do anything. Nothing on console that I can debug.

HTML:

1. div for left button.
2. div for certain width with `overflow:hidden` and another div with width:1000px to keep pictures in a group.
3. right button

note: I test to use jQuery move CSS for 150px each time. I also posted in here. The pictures are different but same code.

jsfiddle.net/bewPromtong/ufvgp

Comment: We need to see the code. We can't theorize.

Comment: share you code and we'll tell you what's wrong with that

Comment: oh... hi .. i just came back to log in. I posted my code at jsfiddle.net/bewPromtong/ufvgp

Answer (score 0):

I sort of messed up your `if/else` statement, but I found a solution to your problem.  You were only setting your `left` to `-150px`, not adding `150px` ontop of the existing value.  To fix this, change your `animate` jquery to this.

```
var leftanimator = function() {
    var $maxL = $('#images').css('left');
    if ($left <= $maxL) {
        return false;
    }else {
    $wrapper.animate({'left':'+=150px' }, 1000);  //this change
    }
    return false;
}
var rightanimator = function() {
    var $right = $('#images').offset().left;
    var $maxR = 0;
    $wrapper.animate({'left':'+=-150px' }, 1000);  //this change
        return false;
}
```

[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ufvgp/1/)

Remember to re add your `if/else` to your right animator function! lol

Comment: Hi derek_duncan, Thanks! it works for the moving but it doesn't stop when the last picture is moved. so how do i go about that though? I try to add+=150 px. before but seems it goes forever.

Comment: Thanks, I am also try to recheck my code as well, in case, I miss something. merci!